# Создать таблицу с динамическим именем

Tags: php, mysql

Название таблицы лежит в переменной $date.

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $date = $_POST['date'];

$result = mysql_query ('select * from $date');
if (!$result)
{
    mysql_query("create table '".$date."' (time time, value int)"); 
}
```

Данный код не срабатывает. Просто таблицу создает. В переменной $date значения тоже есть в нормальном виде.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Несколько рекомендаций:

1. По поводу создания таблиц в MySQL рекомендую почитать [документацию](http://phpclub.ru/mysql/doc/create-table.html).
2. Проверять существует ли таблица как у вас в коде - неправильно. Если таблицы не существует, то попытка обратиться к ней запросом вызовет ошибку и выполнение прервется. Таблицу можно создать с указанием `IF NOT EXISTS`. Она будет создана только в том случае если одноименной таблицы в БД не существует.
3. Переменную с названием таблицы очень желательно фильтровать на предмет лишних символов.  Частично, с помощью [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php), частично - своим фильтром (название - это не строка).
4. Создавать таблицу с именем получаемым извне - потенциальная дыра в защите.
5. И, наконец, создавать таблицы в runtime - плохой тон. За исключением тех случаев, когда разрабатываются скрипты автоматической инсталяции. Но, обычно, такой скрипт отрабатывает один раз и затем удаляется.

Если я правильно понял структуру создаваемой таблицы, то SQL-скрипт для ее создания в вашем случае выглядел бы примерно так:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_name (
    `time` TIME DEFAULT NULL,
    `value` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`time`)
) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

Именно эту конструкцию нужно ложить в строку и скармливать `mysql_query()`.

Comment: Спасибо за рекомендации!

    И, наконец, создавать таблицы в runtime - плохой тон. За        исключением тех случаев, когда разрабатываются скрипты автоматической инсталяции. Но, обычно, такой скрипт отрабатывает один раз и затем удаляется.

Мне просто надо хранить информацию о времени записи на каждый день. Создавать каждый раз эти таблицы вручную как-то не охото. А до другого способа я не додумался..

Comment: Для этого совсем не обязательно каждый раз создавать новую таблицу. Достаточно создать одну с первичных ключом по полю типа `DATETIME`. И писать туда каждый раз значение SQL-функции `NOW()` (текущая дата-время). А для SELECT-выборки любого среза информации в SQL существуют такие вещи как условия, сортировка и группировка.